# How to filter an object based on string from another view

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm displaying a list of drinks in a template. The drinks model has a many-to-many field with tags that group drinks together. I now want to filter the list of drinks based on this tag.
I've made the tag model like this:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    drink_tag = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.drink_tag}"
    
    def get_tag_link(self):
        return reverse('rhumSite:drinkDetailTag',kwargs={'tag':self.drink_tag})
```

This way, each tag has a link to a page that will display all the drins with said tag.
In my URLS.py file the path looks like this:

```
path('cocktails/<str:tag>/',DrinksFilteredListView.as_view(template_name='rhumSite/drinks.html'),name='drinkDetailTag'),
```

When I click on a tag the url is indeed `cocktails/tagname` so that works well.
I now want my listview to take that tag and display all drinks from the drinks model with this tag.

My view looks like this:

```
class DrinksFilteredListView(ListView):
    model = DrinkRecipe
    context_object_name = 'drinks'


    def get_queryset(self):
        return DrinkRecipe.objects.filter(drink_tag__drinkrecipe=self.kwargs['tag'])
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context= super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['tags'] = Tag.objects.all()
        context['tastes'] = TagTaste.objects.all()
        context['bottles'] = Bottle.objects.all()
        return context
```

I know I have to use `get_queryset(self):` but I still struggle with getting the query right. Right now I get the error:

```
Field 'id' expected a number but got 'Summer'.
```

where Summer is indeed the name of the tag.
Any help or insight would be much appreciated.

Edit:
The drinks model looks like this:

```
class DrinkRecipe(models.Model):
    drink_tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    drink_tag_rum = models.ForeignKey(Bottle, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    drink_tag_taste = models.ManyToManyField(TagTaste)
    drink_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    drink_description = HTMLField()
    drink_method = HTMLField()
    drink_garnish = HTMLField()
    drink_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_upload_handler)
    drink_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: What happens if you use `context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)`?

Comment: That fixed the first issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DrinkRecipe.objects.filter(drink_tag__drinkrecipe=self.kwargs['tag']` is checking on tag primary keys (if I understand it right)

I think you want `DrinkRecipe.objects.filter(drink_tag__drink_tag = self.kwargs['tag'] )` assuming `self.kwargs['tag']` is the value of the CharField in a Tag model instance.

The duplication of a field name in `DrinkRecipe` and `Tag` is confusing. It would be better if the field in `Tag` were called `name`. Then you would have code like `tag.name='foo'` and `.filter( drink_tag__name = 'foo')`